# Working with indexes when using Spring boot + Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I know that I can **create** an **index** for both a single column and a composite one. A also I can make an **index** on some expression:

- **create an index** on an expression that searches for data by some condition, while first I specify that the fields first need to be sorted and then output the result by condition, and based on this expression, an **index** is built.

(like an index when working with Couchbase)

```sql
CREATE INDEX `us_users_sorted` ON
`user_profile`(
    `_class`,
    `enabled`,
    `countryCode`,
    `firstName` DESC,
    `lastName` DESC)
WHERE (((`_class` = "com.cb.demo.userProfile.model.UserEntity")
    and (`enabled` = true))
    and (`countryCode` = "US"))
```

But I can't find information about this :

1. If I create a record, will I have to call again in the **same transaction** to **create an index** for this data (the **index** is described above) ?
2. When deleting a record, will I also have to trigger the creation of this **index** again ?
3. When updating , will I have to do this too ?
4. Should I do this via **nativeQuery()** if I use **Spring Data Jpa** ?

I don't see the point in separating this into several questions, in fact this is a question about working with indexes using **Spring** and a relational database.

Maybe someone on the web has seen a detailed example, with all the nuances, when using complex relational database indexes (I don't mean Couchbase) and **Spring data jpa** (**spring boot**)?

If possible, give an answer with an example, please

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Once an index is created it stays there until the index is deleted (not until a row on a table is deleted). And the DB engine will keep it updated and consistent with the data in the table. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Augusto, that is, if I understood correctly, when we created the index once, the DBMS, during deletion, creation and update operations, will automatically recreate the index if the fields on the basis of which the index was created are affected and it is not necessary to manage this from the code?

Comment: The database will maintain the index for you. You don’t have to write code to do this, it’s standard database functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is only need to be created for all the existing records for one time. After that , if an DB record is added/updated/deleted , it just needs to add/update/removed such record from the index rather than creating the whole index again for all records.

You can think that an index just like there exist another `HashMap` which allow you to quickly retrieve a record by some keys . But the DB will help to maintain the content of this HashMap automatically whenever a record is added/updated/deleted in the table that is related to this index. Creating an index just like you initialise the content of this HashMap which only done for one time.

So you should not create an index through native query .You should create it separately upfront before you start the application. Just like you create an DB table.